# numpy binning: how to get array indexes satisfying a predicate

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `g` of values of length 1024 and a smaller vector `f` of size 32 defining bin boundaries. `v` and `f` are sorted in ascending order. I want to return an array of vectors i.e `[v_1,v_2,v_3,...]` of length `len(f)` such that each vector `v_i` contains indices of `g` between `f_i` and `f_i + 1`. Is there a NumPy way to do such a thing that does not involve looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `searchsorted` to find the sorted positions of `f` in `g`.  These give the lower and upper bounds of the ranges that you want:

For example,

```
In [42]: g
Out[42]: 
array([ 1, 11, 19, 20, 21, 32, 36, 41, 47, 53, 54, 55, 65, 66, 69, 74, 76,
       87, 89, 94])

In [43]: f
Out[43]: [0, 10, 20, 50, 100]

In [44]: binedges = g.searchsorted(f)

In [45]: binedges
Out[45]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  9, 20])
```

The array `binedges` gives you all the information that you need: the range of indices for bin `k` is `range(binedges[k], binedges[k+1])`.

Here's how you could create an explicit list of the indices in each bin:

```
In [46]: rngs = [list(range(binedges[k], binedges[k+1])) for k in range(len(binedges)-1)]

In [47]: rngs
Out[47]: [[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

first things first:

```
import numpy as np
```

let's say you have your data `g`:

```
g = sorted((1e3 * np.random.random(1024)).astype(int))
```

and your bins `f`:

```
f = sorted((1e3 * np.random.random(32)).astype(int))
```

you can use `numpy.digitize`, which return the bin indices in `f` where each element of `g` belongs:

```
dg = np.digitize(g,f)
```

The resulting vector is going to contains list of different sizes so you might want to store it is a list:

```
for i in range(len(f)): v.append(np.argwhere(dg == i))
```